# Average torque on a Projectile of mass $m$ with initial speed $u$ and angle of projection $θ$ between initial ($P$) and final ($Q$) positions is

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mathematical-physics, torque, calculus

Question is as follows:
Average torque on a Projectile of mass $m$ with initial speed $u$ and angle of projection $θ$ between initial $(P)$ and final $(Q)$ positions is

I researched a lot but wherever I saw they used the following way

$$\vec{r}=ucos\theta.t$$

$$\vec{F}=mg$$

$$t=\frac{2usin\theta}{g}$$

This implies

$$\vec{\tau_{avg}}=\frac{\vec{r}×\vec{F}}{t}$$

But I want to solve this using integration but I'm not able to.
Kindly help me

Comment: Torque about what point in space? And what does "average torque" mean? That's undefined.. Time averaged, position averaged, other?

Comment: @BillN Average Torque implies sum of torques at each point in the projectile divided by the total time taken to complete the path of the projectile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find torque($\tau$) as a function of time. I am assuming you can do it. If not, let me know.

For averaging it find $$\frac{\int{\tau{dt}}}{t}$$